# Multiple IEM mixes / multiple transmitters?

Tags: mixer

I'm wondering how to have multiple IEM mixes. So the drummer hears a  mix different than the lead vocals mix.
I know one way to do this is, pan some instruments left and right and send mono signals to the transmitters...

But what about multiple transmitters? Each member of the band has their own transmitter and receiver. Mixers don't have 4 aux sends do they? (I haven't bought a mixer yet. I don't know) 
What is the usual way to hook up 4 transmitters? You need to make sure you have enough Aux Sends?

And I don't get how I could cancel out/change the volumes of different instruments and send them to their specific transmitter... I'm new to all this so I definitely need some help haha.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question.  You need to have enough Aux Sends.  If you are using a decent front of house mixer or any monitor mixer, then there will be numerous Aux outputs. (Anything other than the absolute cheapest sound boards should have at least four.) The Presonus StudioLive 24.4.2 that I use most frequently has 10 Aux outputs and it's relatively cheap at $2500 for a 24 channel digital board.

Each Aux send gets it's own mix.  You don't have to "cancel out" anything, you simply don't mix it in to that particular aux send.  Each transmitter is wired up to a particular aux or set of auxes.  (You can normally do left/right pairs of auxes on decent sound boards so that you can send stereo information to the in-ears if you'd like to maintain the vocals/instrument break down, but a little more tuned for each person.)

Another side bonus of some digital boards is that some of them can actually allow the performers themselves to adjust their mix with an iPhone or iPad.